# Select a value from table with different criteria SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

TABLE player

```
idPlayer | name  |

    1    | name1 |
    2    | name2 |
    3    | name3 |
    4    | name4 |
```

Table matches

```
idMatch  |  idPlayer1 | idPlayer2 | date  |

   1     |      1     |     2     | 03-03 |
   2     |      3     |     4     | 03-03 |
   3     |      1     |     4     | 03-03 |
```

Expeted

```
idMatch  |   player1  |   player2 | date  |

   1     |    name1   |    name2  | 03-03 |
   2     |    name3   |    name4  | 03-03 |
   3     |    name1   |    name4  | 03-03 |
```

I have tried many codes and still have not found a solution.

Comment: Please explain what you need, post what you have tried till now and the problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this

```
SELECT idMatch,
(SELECT name FROM t1 WHERE t2.idPlayer1=t1.idPlayer) as name1, 
(SELECT name FROM t1 WHERE t2.idPalyer2=t1.idplayer) as name2, 
date
FROM calendario
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 Select t1.idMatch AS idMatch, p1.name AS player1, p2.name AS player2, t1.date AS date
 FROM matches t1
 INNER JOIN player p1 ON t1.idPlayer1 = p1.idPlayer
 INNER JOIN player p2 ON t1.idPlayer2 = p2.idPlayer
```

This should decode the players properly for you.